# dispatch.fcgi and rails for phusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I experience the following problem: 
On my hosting (www.site5.com) the ruby is quite old - 1.8.7, the server is run under Apache and Phusion Passenger is used for deploying.
The support team installed an RVM, so that I can use ruby 1.9.3. Nevertheless, installing even a simplest rails application, the server reports

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The problem is in configuring dispatch.fcgi and .htaccess files which I present here:

dispatch.fcgi

```
    #!/home/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
    ENV['HOME'] ||= `echo ~`.strip
    ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392')
    ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392') + ":" +
        File.expand_path('~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global')
    require 'fcgi' 
    require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../config/environment.rb')
    class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
     def initialize(app)
       @app = app
     end
     def call(env)
       env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
       parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
       env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
       env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
       @app.call(env)
     end
    end
Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run  Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(try::Application)
```

.htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI 
#Change to your environment
RailsEnv production
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/stats/(.*)$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/failed_auth.html$
 RewriteRule .* - [L]
 RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

The support team tries hard, but so far we have not found way out...

Answer (score 2):

Check that you actually get the version of ruby you think running your dispatch.fcgi, e g by adding a

raise RUBY_VERSION

first in the file and see what output it produces when going to the site with a web browser (hopefully backtraces are presented there, they were in my case.)

I just battled with a similar situation on fsdata.se web hotel. Even with a #!/ shebang line like yours, the file was actually executed by ruby 1.8.7! The workaround to this was making a dispatch.fcgi that only did an exec of the correct ruby version executing the real dispatch script, like this (modified to your paths):

> exec("/usr/bin/env /home/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby /home/foo/[path to your rails app]/public/realdispatch.fcgi")

The contents of realdispatch.fcgi looks similar to your dispatch.fcgi. I got it from [dreamhost](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Rails_3), which has been a good resource page for this.

My .htaccess (generated by fsdata) looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine   On 
RewriteBase     / 
RewriteRule     ^$ index.html [QSA] 
RewriteRule     ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA] 
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

Now, everything works except that my asset urls aren't loaded properly - still working on that one.)

Comment: (UPDATE:... just found the error making the asset urls weird - it had nothing to do with this, so the above should be a proper fix, from what I can tell so far.)

Comment: thanks for the idea! The staff has somehow resolved the issue (thanks to them) so in fact I for me it remained as a mystery. Your answer might be useful for others who battle the problem.